# Truss beam like structure strength per height

Tags: beam, bending, forces, force-measurement

The second beam is 2x the height of the first one.

Is 1 stronger then 2 to bending force (arrow shows direction, supported on the sides)?

If it does, I'm trying to figure out why, because they both rely on the tensile strength of the material at the bottom which is the same (also same thickness, but not same length)

The third one is 2x the height of the first one, but the exposed material at the bottom is at the same length and thickness as the first one, will it make a difference?

[image]

Comment: Why are beams deeper when going over longer distances?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, not sure I understand the question